# Evaluating the indefinite integral $\int\frac{\sqrt{1-x}}{x\sqrt{1+x}}\,dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

$$\int\frac{\sqrt{1-x}}{x\sqrt{1+x}}\,dx$$
Looking at the term under the square root, I tried out the subsitution $x = \cos\theta$. This reduced the expression to $\int(1 - \sec\theta)d\theta$. This doesn't tally with the answer provided though. What is happening?

Comment: What was the answer provided? The substitution looks fine to me.

Comment: The final answer provided is $ln\dfrac{\sqrt{1+x}-\sqrt{1-x}}{\sqrt{1+x}+\sqrt{1-x}} + 2\arctan(\sqrt{\dfrac{1-x}{1+x}})$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $$\displaystyle I = \int\frac{\sqrt{1-x}}{\sqrt{1+x}}\cdot \frac{1}{x}dx = \int\frac{\sqrt{1-x}}{\sqrt{1+x}}\cdot \frac{\sqrt{1-x}}{\sqrt{1-x}}\cdot \frac{1}{x}dx$$

So $$\displaystyle I = \int\frac{1-x}{x\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx = \int\frac{1}{x\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx-\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx$$

Now Put $1-x^2=t^2$ Then $xdx = -tdt$ in $1^{st}$ and $x=\sin \theta$ and $dx = \cos \theta d\theta $ in $2^{nd}$ Integral

So $$\displaystyle I = \int\frac{1}{(t^2-1)}dt-\sin^{-1}(x)+\mathcal{C}$$

So $$I = \ln \left|\frac{t-1}{t+1}\right|-\sin^{-1}(x)+\mathcal{C}$$

So $$I = \ln \left|\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}-1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}+1}\right|-\sin^{-1}(x)+\mathcal{C}$$